# How to pass a json encoded variable from a python function to a in an html embetted js code in flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I have this

```
@app.route('/sensor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def sensor():

output ='''<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><style>body{
    background: #005E60;  
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100vh;
   ...
    }
    </style>   
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    
    function loop(){
            fetch('/loaddata')
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Data received:', data);   <-- this wont work because 
                                                           it is not a json encoded
            })                                             response? Coouldnt get it working
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
            });
        }

    var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
    loop()
    }, 1000);


    </script>
    <body>
    <div class = Box>
    <div class = flex-box>
    <p><a href='http://172.23.2.132:5000/camera' style='width: 210px; height:80px;color:white; font-size: 23px; '>Click here to get back</a></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(data)
    </script>
    </div> </div> 
          
    ''' 


return output
```

the other function:

```
@app.route('/loaddata', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def loaddata():
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',\
    baudrate=57600,\
    timeout=1)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    output2 = ""
    for x in range(8):
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        print(line)    <-- this output in the console works perfect so arduino code should be 
        output2 += line    fine
        time.sleep(1/100)
    print("connected to: " + ser.portstr) 
    return {output2}
```

I want to get the output variable from the python code into the js code.

I get an error from the js code, as it cannot read the python return value, i have tried many things to decode it into json readable data but couldnt get it running. Eventually the ouput from the js code should be displayed on a website

Answer (score 0):

Just put the output in a list and append it and define it et voila

```
@app.route('/loaddata', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def loaddata():
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',\
    baudrate=57600,\
    timeout=1)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    output2 = []
    for x in range(8):
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        print(line)    
        output2.append(line)
        time.sleep(1/100)
    print("connected to: " + ser.portstr) 
    return output2
```